# List inside a List returns Empty after calling List.Clear()

Tags: c#, .net, list

In my code,I do have a List, named `lstDetails`.
It contains another List, named `lstcheckdetails`.
As output, `lstcheckdetails` returns an **empty** list as it calls `Clear` function.
Until now I thought the list will get committed after adding data to it.

Can you help me out?

```
List<AttendanceDetails> lstDetails = new List<AttendanceDetails>();

List<CheckDetails> lstcheckdetails = new List<CheckDetails>();

CheckDetails checkdetails = new CheckDetails();

for loop
{
    if(condition)
    {
       checkdetails.Item1 = item1;
       checkdetails.Item2 = item2;
       lstcheckdetails.Add(checkdetails);
    
    }
    else
    {
       lstDetails.Add(new AttendanceDetails { TimeCard = lstcheckdetails });
       lstcheckdetails.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend reading up on how reference types work in C#. Jon Skeet as always, is a good person to listen to. https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

A quick fix for you piece of code would be `... { TimeCard  = lscheckdetails.ToList(), ...`
This creates a new copy of the list and lets you clear the one in your loop

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted if you want and the question will then be consider 'solved'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading up on how reference types work in C#. Jon Skeet as always, is a good person to listen to. [References and Values](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html) - however there are plenty of sources on this out there

To make a quick summary reference types as their name implies are passed around by reference, so unless you explicitly make a copy of that object (in this case creating a new list by using `.ToList()`) you new object and the loop both point to the same object in memory, that's why called `.Clear()` empties the list in both places you are looking at it.

A quick fix for you piece of code would be ... `{ TimeCard  = lscheckdetails.ToList()`, ... This creates a new copy of the list and lets you clear the one in your loop.